# Where is the Magento2 Order Confirmation sender email address noted?

Tags: magento2.3, order-email

I am experiencing an issue where the sender email address for the order confirmation email is not what is set in the admin panel for Magento 2.3. I have checked both SMTP settings and the store email addresses and none of them match what is being used to send emails. Where would I look in the file structure to find the appropriate file that may contain this email address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual files that you need to check to debug your issue are **SenderBuilder** and **Sender** as given below

its under this path

`vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email`

[Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Email/SenderBuilder.php)

investigate the method

```
/**
     * Configure email template
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureEmailTemplate()
    {
        $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($this->templateContainer->getTemplateId());
        $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateOptions($this->templateContainer->getTemplateOptions());
        $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateVars($this->templateContainer->getTemplateVars());
        $this->transportBuilder->setFromByScope(
            $this->identityContainer->getEmailIdentity(),
            $this->identityContainer->getStore()->getId()
        );
    }
```

[Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender.php)

```
 /**
     * Create Sender object using appropriate template and identity.
     *
     * @return Sender
     */
    protected function getSender()
    {
        return $this->senderBuilderFactory->create(
            [
                'templateContainer' => $this->templateContainer,
                'identityContainer' => $this->identityContainer,
            ]
        );
    }
```

In addition to these files, you can also debug this one , where the From Header is set for all the emails.

[Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php)

> As always, **double check your configuration settings** (`Stores - Configuration - sales - sales email - Order - New Order Confirmation Email Sender`) **in all the scopes** and **clean the config cache**, before you
> dive into debugging.

Hope this helps !